# SQL - Hard time building a "complex" request

Tags: mysql

I've got three tables :

- `conversations` (contains private conversations)
- `conversations-members` - structure : `convId | userId` (contains all ids of members participating to a conversation so multiple people can talk together. One user participating to a conversation equals one row)
- `users` (users table, classic)

What I am trying to do is :

Users have friends. So, the user browsing my application can open a conversation from his friends' ids.

So, first, I want to look up in `conversations-members` if there is an existing conversation ONLY between user's Id and his friend's Id and then, pick up the conversation id in `conversations` table that `conversations-members` gave me.

Is it possible to do this in one request? If I have to do two requests, I don't even know how to build the first one (`find the rows that contain user's Id and friend's Id that have conversation Id in common)`.

My first idea was to make a single `conversations` table which would also contain member's Id in the form of a string like "55,105,85,22" and then parse it to get an array, but I think the way I want to do it gives me more options and could be simpler if I manage to handle the SQL requests I need.

Comment: **in the form of a string like "55,105,85,22"** No, no, a thousand times no. Comma separated values in SQL columns are considered harmful. Read about normalization and denormalization.

Comment: Will do. I am far from a professionnal developper so I am learning while coding. I didn't do it this way anyway.

Comment: Ya get to be a professional dev by making stupid mistakes like denormalizing your data. Don't ask how I know that.  :-)

Comment: Haha. I guess this is a path you have to take at some point when you're learning on your own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find conversations involving just two particular users, you can do something like this.

```
SELECT convId, COUNT(*)
  FROM `conversations-members`
 WHERE userId IN (FIRST_USER, SECOND_USER)
 GROUP BY convId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

The `HAVING` line filters out any conversation with any users besides the two you want.

You can use that as a subquery:

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM conversations
 WHERE convId IN (
          SELECT convId
            FROM `conversations-members`
           WHERE userId IN (FIRST_USER, SECOND_USER)
           GROUP BY convId
          HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
       )
```

If you wanted conversations with your two users and any other users, you could change the subquery to `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2`.

**Pro tip**: SQL thinks hyphens `-` mean subtraction. Avoid them in column and table names.

Comment: @o-jones you have duplicated your answer (xD)

Comment: darn back button. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. This is exactly what I needed! Btw, I renamed my tables with underscores instead of hyphens :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong naming tables [stupidely](https://imgur.com/a/DXP9mHu). `SELECT * FROM [INSERT].[INTO]` worked.

Comment: The only trouble with using reserved words or arithmetic characters to name tables and columns is you must remember to escape them. In SQL server the escape is `[]`. In MySql it's backticks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use a column with multiple values.

When you have a relation 1-N, normally you need to use a table with two keys, for example, ConvID - UserID. Your index are created by these two columns, for don't allow to generate a duplicate (an UserID two times on the same ConvID, for example).

But, in response to your question, yes, it's possible to do that search. You need to search for an entry on your SQL table where two different IDs are on the same line. You can do it with LIKE clause, but it's not a good option (I think it's the worst possible WHERE clause).

The syntax will be as follows:

```
SELECT convId FROM conversations-members WHERE userId LIKE '%id1%' AND userId LIKE '%id2%'
```

For some additional recommendation, if your conversations are always a pair of people, use two new fields on your "conversations" table. If your conversation can have from one to N members, use the "conversations-members" as suggested at the start of the answer.

Comment: Imagine you have 500 users in your table. user 10 and 25 are friends. There is a conv stored that way : `1 | 100,250`. Your query will fetch that value which isn't desired

Comment: I think my post wasn't clear enough because I didn't use a column with multiple values. I did exactly what you described in the first part of your post. I explained that using a column with multiple values was my first idea, but then I decided to use another table with two columns. Though, it's good to know that I can use the LIKE operator to make requests with multiple values. I didn't think of that, thanks

Comment: @cid, for solving this, then they need to store values always starting and ending with a comma (for example, if comma its the value separator), and then, user them on the LIKE's, as: '%,id1,%'. I've only try to do a solution for the question, even if it's a "bad" practice. Result on table will be some like ,10,20,500, but you can do "exact" searches then.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto yes, that's a workaround, but as you stated in your answer, this is a bad practice

Comment: Sometimes, you also need to know how to "save" your time with bad practices. You didn't imagine what I've found on some SQL's of clients. And without option to fix it. It's not bad to explain how to work with data incorrectly formatted / stored, if you stated correctly you will never do if you can create your own data-model.